# Use of instanceof operator

Tags: java

This code says that downcasting will be performed here with no exception thrown.But the object( a )was already of class Dog3,then why to downcast it again ? when i made this object(a) of class animal and then tried to downcast it exception was thrown.But in java tpoint it says this is possible with instanceof operator.Is it so ?

```
class Animal 
{
 }  

class Dog3 extends Animal 
{  
  static void method(Animal a)
 {  
    if(a instanceof Dog3){  
       Dog3 d=(Dog3)a;//downcasting  
       System.out.println("ok downcasting performed");  
    }  
  }  

  public static void main (String [] args)
 {  
    Animal a=new Dog3();  
    Dog3.method(a);  
  }  

 }
```

Comment: Because the type of the method parameter is `Animal`, different code could cause the downcast to not be done.

Answer (score 1):

Your object, that is on the heap, is of type `Dog3` and will not change of course. But the reference pointing to it could be of `Dog3` or `anything super Dog3` and you should change that if you want to use a `Dog3` reference, for example to use some specific methods from the `Dog3` class

Comment: okay i got your point but my point this downcasting can be performed without the help of instanceof operator.Then what is it's use ?

Comment: @MrinalAhuja Because if your object `a` was actually a `Cat` and not a `Dog` then your program would crash when you try to downcast to a `Dog`. That's why you check with `instanceof` to make sure that `a` is a `Dog` before you downcast to a `Dog`. You don't have to use `instanceof` before you downcast, but you should.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you add the following to your main method:

```
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {  
    Animal a=new Dog3();  
    Dog3.method(a); 
    Animal a2 = new Animal();
    Dog3.method( a2 ); 
  }
```

In the second invocation of `method` the downcast will not occur.  The second invocation shows that an `Animal` could be passed into your method, so you have to account for that possibility in the method body, or sometimes your method will throw an exception.

Comment: Thats okay but my point this downcasting can be performed without the help of instanceof operator.Then what is it's use ??

Comment: How can you down cast?

Comment: class Animal { }  
  
class Dog3 extends Animal {  
  static void method(Animal a) {  
    
       Dog3 d=(Dog3)a;//downcasting  
       System.out.println("ok downcasting performed");  
     
  }  
   
  public static void main (String [] args) {  
    Animal a=new Dog3();  
    Dog3.method(a);  
  }  
    
 }     even this code works fine without the use of instanceof operator

Comment: Animal a=new Animal();  
Dog.method(a);  
//Now ClassCastException but not in case of instanceof operator.this is what javatpoint says.

Comment: Yup, so the `instanceof` operator is required to prevent that error.

Comment: i tried this without instanceof and there is no error.Thats what i am saying.ANd tpoint says i can downcast an object of animal class.

Comment: You can't.  I know that error occurs if you try to downcast something that isn't a `Dog`, so you're talking about something different, or you've simply made a mistake reading your code.